# Is it true that if we have $R\subset E$ an irreducible root system then $E$ is an irreducible representation of the Weyl group?

Tags: lie-algebras, weyl-group

Recently in my class of lie algebra the profesor said the following statement

> If we have $R\subset E$ (with $E$ The Euclidean space) an  irreducible root system then $E$ is an irreducible representation of the Weyl group.

The thing is that he didn't proved it as he said it casually, but I wrote it on my notes. So, I wanted to prove it, but I tried and fail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is $E$ supposed to be the Euclidean space containing the root system?

Comment: Yes its the Euclidean space

Comment: Where did your attempt fail? Did you get so far that it's a representation at all? What did you try for irreducibility?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg what I tried to do was first find the invariant subpaces of $E$ under the Weyl group (which are reflections) in theory I would need to have that the invariant subpace is the plane and the orthogonal to it, but I didn't manage to do it. After that I had the idea of proving that there are no non trivial invariant subpaces. I don't know if this isdea correct.

Comment: That's the idea, you take a nonzero invariant subspace and show it's the full space. Somewhere you will have to use the root system is irreducible.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg could you help me a little bit, as I have been unable to do it for a while now ? Hehe

Comment: This depends a lot on what you know already about how the Weyl group acts on the roots. For example, do you know which roots you can send to each other via the Weyl group? Has that been covered in class? If not, maybe that's why your prof only mentioned the statement, because without that knowledge, it's hard to prove.